# store array into global variable angular

Tags: arrays, angular, global-variables

I am trying to save the `value` of parse `array` into global `array`.
but global `array` showing me `undefined`

```
  dataUrl: string = "assets/data.csv";
  private data:[];
dataInit(){
    this.papa.parse(this.dataUrl, {
      download: true,
      complete: (result) => {
        // result.data.push(this.data);
        this.data = result.data
        // console.log(result.data, "inside parser");
        // console.log(this.data, "global array");
      }

    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataInit();
    console.log(this.data, "inside onInit");
}
```

**Console**

`undefined "inside onInit"`

Comment: Try to initialize `data` like `private data:[] = [];`

Comment: in this case, the data show `Array (0)`

Comment: I think `console.log(this.data, "inside onInit");` prints before your `this.dataInit();` method completes the execution. Try to un-comment `// console.log(result.data, "inside parser");` and check.

Comment: @hrdisback, yes exactly this is the case. How can I access the array value out the side `dataInit` function?

Comment: You can use `timeout` block, you can use `promise` and `observables` check this for ref. https://medium.com/mr-frontend-community/understand-async-await-in-typescript-in-only-a-few-minutes-dedb5a18a2c

Answer (score 1):

The data will be available inside `complete callback`. So `console.log(this.data)` over there.

> Reason: **`complete` is a callback method which works asynchronously.**

```
dataUrl: string = "assets/data.csv";
data = [];
dataInit(){
    this.papa.parse(this.dataUrl, {
      download: true,
      complete: (result) => {
        // result.data.push(this.data);
        this.data = result.data            
        console.log(this.data);
      }

    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataInit();
}
```

Comment: Yes, console show the data inside the `papa.parse()` function.I need to push the parse array into global array to access data in other functions. Is there any other approach to push the **csv** data into global?

Comment: @FaisalJanjua, you can access this.data in any functions as it is already in your 
this variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons for that -

1. You need to initilize the variable like this `private data: Array<any>= [];`
2. You are binding the value into asyn method and consoling the value in synchronous way.

Comment: you are right, but do we have any approach to get the value into global and reuse is when we need?

Answer (score 0):

Change the initialization of the data property to something like

```
private data = [];
```

Or

```
private data: Array<T> = []
```

Instead of **T** type your array accordingly

Comment: I tried both `private data:[] = [];` and `private data = []` both show `Array(0)`.

Comment: Are you pushing in the results contents in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Put the console log inside the complete function of the async code.

Because the `papa.parse` download code is asynchronous, the console log will show the initial value of `data` because the results are not ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

Because this.papa.parse function is asynchronous, you can't get value of data variable right after calling dataInit... better to do inside complete callback

```
dataUrl: string = "assets/data.csv";
private data:[];
dataInit() {
  this.papa.parse(this.dataUrl, {
    download: true,
    complete: (result) => {
      this.data = result.data
      this.toDo();
    }
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataInit();
}

toDo(){
  console.log(this.data, "global array");
}
```